# Is there a way to target a particular item in a list if it is not the first item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, if-statement

```
pist = ['P58', 'P60', 'P0']

def print_it:
   For i in pist:
        if i == 'P0':
            print('yes')

        elif i == 'P58':
            print('yup')

        else:
            print('No')
```

So this is the issue:
I want the function to print 'yes' as long as P0 is in the list(irrespective of whether P58 is in it) but it keeps printing 'yup' because P58 is the first item on the list. Can there be another way?
Note: the list cannot be changed.

Comment: `if 'P58' in pist:` no need for a loop

Comment: Please update your question with the required output.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why does the code print `yup` for `P58` when you say you want it to print `yes`.

Comment: I'd rename you function from `print` to something that is not the same name as a built-in function

Comment: The function is probably not named `print()` or they'd be getting an infinite recursion error.

Comment: The function should actually be printing `Yup` then `No` then `Yes`. It prints a different message for each element depending on whether it's `P58`, `P0`, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print():
    if 'P0' in pist:
        return 'yes'
    elif 'P58' in pist:
        return 'yup'
    else:
        return 'No'
```

Comment: I have made changes to the question.  Using 'in' still does not give me what i want

Comment: corrected - just change order of the tests.